# How to ignore test files(_test.go) using go/analysis?

Tags: go, golint

How to ignore test files(_test.go) using go/analysis? It seems like that go/analysis load test files by default.

Comment: Show your code that loads the files for analysis.

Comment: I use `func main() { singlechecker.Main(diggen.Analyzer) }`  to run analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

This was mentioned in Oct. 2020 with [`golang/go` issue 41771](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41771):

It was discussed in [`leighmcculloch/gochecknoglobals` PR 16](https://github.com/leighmcculloch/gochecknoglobals/pull/16), but so far (Sept. 2021), without any clear resolution.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29258

Answer (score 0):

Singlechecker assumes tests are enabled by default and -test=false disables them.